# what is best for making dynamic screens?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm about to make an app that involves a lot of screens, its data structure is a tree with 4 levels and 84 final nodes that will contain check boxes at the end, I was thinking in using fragments but I dont want to make all that fragments, I am thinking there must be a more efficient way like to make a dynamic fragment that could load all the information (like text for the title or the check boxes) from a server or a data base, any ideas or suggestions for what could be easier and more efficient?

Comment: Do you mean you want your UI/Layouts to be dynamic?

Comment: yes, I want to add screens dynamically so that I can add nodes in the server and the app automatically change or add the nodes, otherwise if I add or change something I wil have to do it manually in the app

Comment: It's difficult without a lot of code, at least to me on the client side. You could use a web view, and load the content from the server in one activity or fragment. Or if you've heard of `ReactNative` by facebook. You have to know `JavaScript`, though. You could leverage that. Read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). And how it can be used to create views on your server and have your app load it, [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/so-you-want-to-dynamically-update-your-react-native-app-d1d88bf11ede#.1skrojkvo)